# Windows XP - VirtualAlloc() how to (where is memoryapi.h???)

Tags: c, assembly, memory-management, windows-xp

I need to use VirtualAlloc() on a C code application in order to run a piece of assembly code using memory pointer. I'm trying to build the code on Windows XP 32 bit for a testing purpose but I can't find a way to use VirtualAlloc().

I installed the last available Visual C++ Redistributable package using the suggestion of Microsoft from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Any tip? Thank you

Comment: [VirtualAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) There you go. That describes how to call the function.

Comment: Maybe I was not so clear with the title (I'll change it): there isn't memoryapi.h on Windows XP

Comment: You can locate it in windows.h but for that you will need the windows sdk which you can install along with Microsoft’s compiler using Visual Studio

Comment: I'm using mingw, yes, the correct header is windows.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I coded for Windows XP, VirtualAlloc was found in windows.h. If you can't locate it, copy/paste the declaration.

```
LPVOID WINAPI VirtualAlloc(LPVOID lpaddress, SIZE_T size, DWORD flAllocationType, DWORD flProtect);
```

Comment: Right answer, windows.h is the correct header, thank you